# How to force NSURLSession to send data without truncation / conversion

Tags: ios, node.js, http, caching, nsurlsession

Sending data with `NSURLSession`. Sent package length is **8278**, but server receives only **8029** byte. How can I prevent to happen this?

```
let field2 = field as! FieldAsset
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let path = (documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Assets") as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(upsert.recordName).\(field2.key)")
let urlFrom = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "xxx")!
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlFrom)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cache-Control")
request.setValue("\(upsert.recordName).\(field.key)", forHTTPHeaderField: "filename")

let cache = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
cache.requestCachePolicy = .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
NSURLSession(configuration: cache).uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromFile: urlFrom).resume()
```

Found this interesting article: https://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/specs/rfc7230.html#rfc.section.5.7.2

Comment: Are you sure that the request wasn't just gzip'ed? Are you looking at the final asset received by the server, or perhaps just looking at the `Content-Length` header? I might suggest watching the request with a tool like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) and see what was really sent.

Comment: Completely unrelated observation, but you can avoid the `NSString` cast by using `NSURL` methods, e.g. `let urlFrom = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false).URLByAppendingPathComponent("Assets").URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(upsert.recordName).\(field2.key)")`.